# failing to use R, can't manipulate UI via java code

Tags: android, android-widget

I have multiple buttons on the same activity each invoking the method "guessMade()" when they are clicked.

Every time a button is clicked, I would like to set the name of that button as the message that is going to be displayed in a `TextView`. Needless to say, `TextView` is also already created.

My code is as follows:

```
public void guessMade(View view){
    CharSequence s = ((Button)view).getText();
    TextView t = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    t.setText(s);
}
```

Where do I fail ?

Comment: What's the problem? A compile error? If so, what? An exception? If so, what?

Comment: the R tag doesn't really belong here, it's for the R programming language. the R class for Android just stands for "resources" I believe.

Comment: Also, what's the layout's XML code?

Comment: my mistake about the R tag sorry

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx: EDIT: Ignore me - I came in after the tag was removed.

Comment: in XML there are just bunch of buttons declared as well as the textview that I was mentioning, it is named as textView1 as is called in the second line but I can post it if you wish

Comment: Again, what's the problem here? Compile error?

Comment: @EboMike: I was talking about the tag. I know what the R class is (at least a little bit).

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx: Yep, sorry. I refreshed the page after the tag had been removed already.

Comment: no it's a run time error, when I run the code in a physical device it says the program terminated abnormally at this method

Comment: In that case, what's the logcat output?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there is probably something wrong with your variable "s".

try replacing

```
t.setText(s);
```

with

```
t.setText("hello");
```

and see if it works.

Comment: It didn't work that way too. The problem should be on the second line.

Comment: or with setText. try doing something other than setText with "t".

Comment: you were right, the problem is with setting the text, do you know how I can change the text on a textView ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you problem comes with the passed `View`:

- First, you cast the passed `View` to a `Button` and get it's text.
  Okay until here.
- The next step, you use the passed `View` to get the `TextView` that
  you want to use for displaying the Text.

The problem is, that your passed view can only be the `Button` or a collection of Views (a Layout).

You'll want to use

```
TextView t = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

to get your `View`, since using the [`findViewById()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29):

> Look for a **child** view with the given id.

Using `this` will work if this code is placed inside a class which extends `Activity`. If this code is not located in such a class, you can either:

- Pass a `Context`-Object from a Activity or
- use the [`getContext()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29) of the passed View.